# a Xcode project build system requires Java 7 or later

Tags: java, ios, xcode

First,My English is not very well,I hope you can understand what does I mean.
The project is here-->https://github.com/edx/edx-app-ios
When I run it on my Xcode,it has error -->" No Java runtime present, requesting install.
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1"
And then,I install the "jre-8u101-macosx-x64",but it does not work,what should I do?
Thank you!

Comment: Did you set JAVA_HOME?

Comment: I think I have no set JAVA_HOME